# How to compare two arrayList's objects elements in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to compare one arrayList object elements contains another arraylist with below code but this is not working as i expected can some one help me please

```
arrayList1=[{productSku:"123"},{productSku:"1234"}]
arrayList2=[{productSku:"123"},{productSku:"1000"}]
```

My scenario is if arraylist1 elements not matching with any of the element in arraylist2 then we should throw exception

```
arrayList2.stream().filter(type -> "EQUIPMENT".equals(type.getItemType()))
                        .forEach(action -> {                             
            arrayList1.forEach(action1 -> {
                                if (!action1.getProductSku().equalsIgnoreCase(action.getProductSKU())) {
                                    // Throw exception
                                }
                            });
                        });
```

Comment: Define not matching. What is the epected result of your example? Why?

Comment: Just to clarify: you throw the exception when NO element from arraylist1 matches any element of arraylist? or do you even throw the exception when only one element from arraylist1 can't be found in arraylist?

Comment: i want to throw exception  when NO element from arraylist1 matches any element of arraylist2

Answer (score 2):

While Deadpool's answer is great, I'd be more inclined to avoid using `Optional` here, as there is no use for the actual value to be used.

Also, creating a `Stream` for each element traversing the `Stream` is not a good idea in terms of performance.

```java
Set<String> products = arrayList1.stream()
                                 .map(Action::getProductSku)
                                 .map(String::toUpperCase)
                                 .collect(toSet());

boolean shouldThrowAnException = arrayList2.stream()
                                           .filter(type -> "EQUIPMENT".equals(type.getItemType()))
                                           .map(Action::getProductSku)
                                           .map(String::toUpperCase)
                                           .noneMatch(products::contains);

if (shouldThrowAnException) {
    // throw exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stream the `arrayList2` and try finding at least one matching element in `arrayList1` using [findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) or else throw exception

```
arrayList2.stream()
     .filter(type -> "EQUIPMENT".equals(type.getItemType()))
     .filter(list2-> arrayList1.stream()
           .anyMatch(list1->list1.getProductSku().equals(list2.getProductSku())))
     .findFirst()
     .orElseThrow(//some exception)
```